# Upgrading to Backbone 1.0

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to upgrade to Backbone 1.0 from the 0.9 series.

In my backbone app, when I call collection.fetch() I bind on the reset event.  Unfortunately this no longer works as of 1.0:

> Renamed Collection's "update" to set, for parallelism with the similar
>   model.set(), and contrast with reset. It's now the default updating
>   mechanism after a fetch. If you'd like to continue using "reset", pass
>   {reset: true}

So to trigger a reset event I can do this:

```
this.collection.fetch({reset: true})
```

Working again, however I would rather not have to go through all the code and update every collection.fetch().  Is there a way to configure collection.fetch() to automatically pass reset : true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could always override fetch where you've extended your own Backbone collection so it always included that as an option:

```
fetch: function (options) {
    options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
    options.reset = true;
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
}
```

Then every time you call fetch it will already include that as an option and you won't have to modify it wherever you actually make the fetch calls.